# AiForms.Effect for .NET MAUI?

Tags: migration, maui, effect

Is there a library similar to [AiForms.Effect](https://github.com/muak/AiForms.Effects) for .NET MAUI?

I am migrating my application from xamarin.forms to .NET MAUI, we were using this library to fit our design with our designer and add styles that are not available by default on some component (like rounded border, color border, borded width on entry, etc...).

However, I can't find a similar library. So I call on your knowledge!

Comment: There are many 3rd party libs for UI. Telerik, Syncfusion, DevExpress, etc. Some are paid, some are free, some are free for small company/indie developers. Most of this what you want, can be achieved using custom controls (for example Border visual element, where you set RoundRectangle with certain radius, color, thickness etc...) Without having to write platform specific code, and dealing with issues/bugs and waiting for indie dev's to find time to update their lib when something new comes out. I advise against use of such libs.